# Nginx Mapped Hard Drive | Network Sharing

Tags: nginx

I connected my computers up and I am sharing my hard drives with each other.

Both computers have C:/ Drives but when you look at the opposite computers hard drive it says Z:/ Because of the way i mapped them.

But i cant get nginx to pull files from the opposite hard drive on the other computer can anyone give me advice on how to make this work.

```
root   Z:/server/websites/ps/public_www;
```

It just gives a 404 not found when it is on that hard drive. (For all media files)

My full config.

```
    server {
    listen  80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  domain.com www.domain.com;

    root   z:/server/websites/ps/public_www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm default.html default.htm;
    location / {
    root   z:/server/websites/ps/public_www;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    expires 3s;
    max_ranges 0;
    }
    location ~ \.flv$ {
    flv;
    limit_rate 200k;
    root   z:/server/websites/ps/public_www;
    expires max;
    }
    location ~ \.mp4$ {
    limit_rate 200k;
    root   z:/server/websites/ps/public_www;
    expires max;
    }
    location ~ \.gif$ {
    limit_rate 50k;
    root   z:/server/websites/ps/public_www;
    expires max;
    }
    location ~* \.(avi|m4v|mov|divx|webm|ogg|mp3|mpeg|mpg|zip|rar)$ {
    limit_rate 90k;
    root   z:/server/websites/ps/public_www;
    expires max;
    }
    location ~* \.(ico|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|flv|mp4|avi|m4v|mov|divx|webm|ogg|mp3|mpeg|mpg|swf|css|js|txt|zip|rar|xml)$ {
    root   z:/server/websites/ps/public_www;
    expires max;
    }
    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
    return 404;
    }
    location ~ ^/(xampp|security|phpmyadmin|licenses|webalizer|server-status|server-info|cpanel|configuration.php) {
    return 404;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my issue was because of Nginx's open_file_cache
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#open_file_cache

As we discussed via the nginx mailing list.
http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,249008,249036#msg-249036

I nulled out these lines of my http server.

```
#open_file_cache max=900000 inactive=10m;
#open_file_cache_valid 20m;
#open_file_cache_min_uses 1;
#open_file_cache_errors on;
```

And now my Nginx windows Network sharing and mapped hard drives all work fine with no more 404 errors.

Aswell as doing this to fix the error i used http://support.microsoft.com/kb/297684

The fix it tool microsoft provide and the error is still gone.

Or via command line (cmd command prompt).

```
net config server /autodisconnect:-1
net use /persistent:yes
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on my install:

```
location / {
        root   z:/public_html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
```

and it works. This assumes that z:/public_html is where your html files are.

Based on your example, you'd do something like:

```
location / {
        root   z:/server/websites/ps/public_www;;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
```

If that doesn't work, then post your full configuration.

Comment: With two semi colons or just the one ?

Comment: I also just edited the original post to show my full current config.

Comment: Still no luck i get a error everytime i try and access jpg,mp4,flv etc basically any media file and the error is a 404 not found.

Comment: Try removing the root and index blocks from the server block. Leave it only in the location block.

Comment: Same issue :( I don't think Nginx is compatible with windows network and sharing.

Comment: Maybe try reinstalling Nginx with the default config, and then just change the location to your z:/ path, and once you have that working, adjust the config little by little, testing after each small change.